# Slide Out jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu

So I'm trying to code a simple slide out menu with the following script

```
$( "#menu-mini-btn" ).click(function() {
      $("#menu-mini").toggleClass("show-menu");     
});
```

This is the html layout:

```
<ul id="menu-mini">
        <li><a href="#item1">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3">Item3</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="menu-mini-btn">Button</a>
```

id #menu-mini contains a few links that anchor to areas on my page. How do I make it so that when you click on an anchor, it closes the slide out menu?

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Can you put your whole code here?

Comment: put your code at http://jsfiddle.net/ and share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to attach a click event to the anchors within `#menu-mini` and remove the class.

```
$('#menu-mini a').click(function(){
  $('#menu-mini').removeClass('show-menu');
});
```